# Unwanted blue border on radio button, is possible to remove that?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I don't know how to configure or disable it.

I have this css:

```css
.radioButton {
    -fx-font: 13px sans-serif;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}
```

[image: This is my rabio button, and is possible to see a blue border]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try using the CSS selector `input[type="radio"]:checked` and then changing the style.

Comment: These type of selectors don't work in Javafx. Just by changing the background it works. I thought this had an property like "outline-color: transparent;" in web css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue border you're seeing is the result of the `RadioButton` being focused.

You can prevent the `RadioButton` from receiving the focus automatically by setting `focusTraversable` to `false`:

```css
.radio-button {
    -fx-focus-traversable: false;
}
```

To modify the color, you can assign the `-fx-focus-color` and `-fx-faint-focus-color` properties:

```css
.radio-button {
    -fx-focus-color: red;

    /* 2/15 th of the opacity of the focus color */
    -fx-faint-focus-color: ladder(#222, transparent 0%, -fx-focus-color 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just changing the background-color.

```css
.radio-button .radio {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

[image: it works!]